# ASP.net Core Eager Loading data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
public IActionResult Index(){
     return View(_context.Announcements.Include(x => x.Automobile).Include(x=>x.Location));
}
```

And, I want to show Location info on the view. However, on the view data of location can not be show. On the view, location data shows Turbo.Models.Location.

```
@foreach(var announce in Model)
{
 <p>@announce.Location</p>
}
```

I wrote this code on the view.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Everything is good but you have one mistake on the view.

You should write

```
@foreach(var announce in Model)
{
 <p>@announce.Location.Name</p>
}
```

Because if you are write `@announce.Location` you are showing only location of model. However, if you are writing `@announce.Location.Name` you are giving data on the view.